# Elastic net parameters tuning

Tags: goodness-of-fit, regularization

My goal is time series  forecasting. I have several external regressors   as : promo budget, discount percent etc. I want to determine alpha and lambda parameters for elasticnet model. How can i do this? Common k-fold CV is not appropriate because i have deal with time series. Should i do something like CV for time series (rolling origin), but in this case what should i choose as a measure of model quality?

Comment: Rolling origin seems fine. What measures of model quality were you considering, and what are your doubts about this?

Comment: The usual issue with time series is that it violates basic principles of cross-validation (that the split is random), but I don't think there is (or ever will be) a solution for that. So I think the only thing you can do really is rolling split

Comment: I want to use something like AIC  for quality measurement, but i dont know how to calculate it. Another measure is explained deviance ratio . Is it representative in model with elasticnet regularization?